# Implement permissions on this exported component

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-automotive

I am coding an application for Android Automotive OS. It is a simple Hello World for now, but that is not the problem of the app so far.

To run the app in the in-built automotive emulator of Android Studio (I use the Canary version of Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Canary 10) I had to download an app called **Google Automotive App Host**, gonna refer to them as **GAAH** from now on, to be able to run my own created app. So far so good.

Now I came across a "problem" in my `AndroidManifest.xml` which says:
`Implement permissions on this exported component.` in the <service> section:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/example_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/example_icon_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Example">

        <meta-data
            android:name="androidx.car.app.minCarApiLevel"
            android:value="1" />

        <service
            android:name="com.example.launcher.services.LauncherService"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.car.app.CarAppService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name="androidx.car.app.activity.CarAppActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="distractionOptimized"
                android:value="true" />
        </activity>

    </application>
```

Most of the answers stated, that `android:exported` should be set to `false`, which makes sense, so other apps don't have access to my own app.

The problem is, it also includes the aforementioned GAAH, which I need to be able to run it at all. It is not something game-breaking, it is just an inconvenience to deal with.

My question is: Are there ways to fix this issue **and** retain the ability for GAAH to run my app in AAOS?

Thanks in advance!
Grey

Edit: Expanded the XML section from <service> to <application>

Answer (score 1):

The Google Automotive App Host holds the `android.car.permission.TEMPLATE_RENDERER` permission, so you should be able to use that as follows:

```xml
<service
   android:name=(hidden)
   android:exported="true"
   android:permission="android.car.permission.TEMPLATE_RENDERER">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="androidx.car.app.CarAppService" />
   </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Additionally, you can further refine which hosts you trust by overriding the [CarAppService::createHostValidator](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/car/app/CarAppService#createHostValidator()) method.

Comment: Sadly, as expected, `java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent` is thrown. Did I forgot something? I would be glad to know.

Comment: Hmm, do you have a longer log? Using `android:permission="android.car.permission.TEMPLATE_RENDERER"` works for me (and changing it to `android:permission="android.car.permission.FOO"` breaks, so the value is definitely being used).

Comment: I think this is all I get. The logs are in the [album](https://imgur.com/a/H16cInY). My service class is the same as Google's example [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/car/app/CarAppService#createHostValidator())